# Saving and loading the FORM value in a better practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have dropdown selections on the page.

The code looks like

```
<td>
    <ui-select ng-model="user_profile.gender" required="true">
    <ui-select-match > {{$select.selected.name}} </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="option in selectOptions.gender | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} ">
    <div ng-bind-html="option.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</td>
```

## Javascript side.

```
var selectOptions = {
    gender: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "女"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: "男"
    }],
    ..
}
```

However, the value on the field in the database is a INTEGER type.

0 for women, 1 for men

How could I load the gender value from database to the page without too many hard-code procedure.

Because I can think of a stupid way like that

For loading page

- load the gender value from API.
- set the selected value of the gender dropdown list

For saving changes

- extract the selected value of the gender dropdown list
- send PUT request to the API for saving changes

Wow, it should involving lots of logic of implementing the code.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this on Angular.js or any javascript library to handle the conversions.

Thank you

Comment: May be I am stupid too, I think the same way as you do :-)

Comment: I think the similar work flow is a must, but is there any handy lib can help us write less code. such as `ngResource` save much time to write lots of code for negotiating with web server :(

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is to match the Id value in the repeat of the ui-select then you just need to change:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="option in selectOptions.gender | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} ">
```

to:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="option.id as option in selectOptions.gender | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} ">
```

Reason being is you are currently just saying I want to use this entire model as the selected value. By stating "options.id as option" says I will give you the whole object to use in the repeat but when something is selected I will set the id as the selected value and use that as the compare for setting the value.

Quick example is at https://plnkr.co/edit/G8FHfauHd2auSYdRUlDB?p=preview